# Привести [преобразование-типов] к одному типу

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие вот похожие друг на друга метки:

- [преобразования-типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0) (1 вопрос)
- [преобразование-типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2) (104 вопроса)

Надо бы их синонимизировать.

Comment: Приведение и преобразование — это не одно и то же. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499400/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но по крайней мере `преобразования-типа` и `преобразования-типов` синонимизировать нужно точно. Поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 1 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 1 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 1 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'преобразования-типа': [преобразования-типа] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 105
tag remapping of [преобразование-типов] and [преобразования-типа] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym преобразования-типа -> преобразование-типов was approved!
```